# Smarty: passing an array to template with ajax, getting "null"

Tags: smarty

May you help me to find solution for this problem: I made an array in controller, var_dump shows it's content, but when I'm trying to pass it in template (with ajax), it gets only "null" value. 
Notable, when I use firebug to preview what data was passed, I see only result from var_dump in controller. Also template file is writable and accessible.

**controller:**

```
...
$series_size = some sql result;
$this->view->assign('series_size', $series_size);
pre($series_size[0]);
```

**view (module.series_ajax.tpl):**

```
{$series_size|@var_dump}
```

Comment: you should edit your question and add some code sample

Comment: You should explain more and show more code.